# Joomla 2.5 - Looking to append info to certain article URLs based on category

Tags: php, url, joomla2.5

I have a site I'm building where there is a module for podcasts/radio show episodes. If you go to the page normally through the main navigation, it will load the latest show. What I would like though is for the player to load a specific show if you click on one of the article links. So each article is linked to particular show and if you click on it, I'd like to pass the ID info through the URL. Something like ?podcast_id=2 appended to the end of the URL. Does anyone have any thoughts? I was trying to mess with K2 and see if I could find something suitable there but it conflicts with my Disqus plugin.

I'd also like to add a field in the article creation to input the ID of the show. Thoughts on this would be appreciated as well.

Link to follow:

http://www.grindhardnetwork.com/grind_hard_site/radio-show-2.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going to suggest K2 plus K2 BNR content so you could put the podcast in a module position. This would make it very easy to do, it might be worth looking in to fixing the conflict and doing it this way.

If not, then you can use a combination of adding custom fields to your Joomla articles, then using alternative layouts to display the podcast.

Adding custom fields - http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_custom_fields_to_the_article_component

Alternative layouts - http://docs.joomla.org/Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla_1.6#Introduction_to_Alternative_Layout_Feature_in_Version_1.6

Comment: The custom fields will certainly help but what about appending that info to the end of the Readmore and article link? I'd need to either add podcast_id=2 so I can use $_GET['podcast_id'] to get the info and load up the appropriate podcast file or if there is an easier/more efficient way to send this info, I'd be open to using that method.

Comment: One of the custom fields should be the URL to the podcast associated with the article. There would be no need to pass any additional variables as the value you need would be stored along with the article.

Comment: That would work, but how would I pull up the info in the module? I am currently using the podcast_id from the URL as a case. If it is not set then load the latest podcast.

Comment: Putting the extra field in a module is a little harder. It's going to take a custom module to achieve that. The reason I was going to suggest K2 in the first place is because we built BNR K2 Content to do exactly what you need. It displays potions of the current K2 item in a module position and it supports multiple instances on a page. This allows you to put the podcast in a column, the main image in a header, and the attachments in another column for example. You need BNR k2 content for Joomla com_content. Download it and look at the code, it should not be hard to adapt to com_content.